# How to test two different objects have same values

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing test for my code with Mockito and JUnit. Everything was so good so far but know I am having `StackOverFlow` error. I think, I am getting that error because my objects are nested. For example A object has relation with B object and B object also has relation with A object.

I am testing if my objects have same values like this

```java
assertEquals(objectA.toString(), objectB.toString());
```

I want to delete `@ToString` annotation from my both object to handle `StackOverFlow` error but I do not know how to test two different objects are equal or no. I saw some topics in here and they are telling use `assertThat` but I do not have that too.

how can I test that the values of two different objects are the same? Also, if you have any other solution, I would like to hear.

Comment: Write an `equals` method for the class. But keep in mind that you might still run into the same issue with infinite recursion there.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thank you but I think I need another solution. As you mentioned that I might have the same issue

Comment: As @JoachimSauer You have to write equals method and write it in a way to avoid recursion, manually get the value of all the fields and compare them. Thats the easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks all of you guys. I have too many objects and attributes. Therefore, your suggestions require a lot of changes on the source code. I didn't want to make that while I am just testing my services. I found similar problem in [here](https://groups.google.com/g/project-lombok/c/Xr13lPinsvg). I fixed the problem with `@ToString.Exclude` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Override equals method and use `assertEquals:` You can override the equals method in your objects to compare the relevant fields for equality. Then you can use `assertEquals` to compare the entire objects.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    ObjectA other = (ObjectA) obj;
    return Objects.equals(field1, other.field1) &&
           Objects.equals(field2, other.field2) &&
           // Repeat for other fields
}

// In your test
assertEquals(objectA, objectB);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [Kedar Thakkar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76661557/22190461)'s answer should work and it's how it should be done, but if you're still getting an infinite recursion problem, then you can just check each field you want to compare separately. You can write a method that takes both objects and returns if their values are equal, for example:

```
public boolean compareFields(Object objectA, Object objectB) {

  if (objectA == objectB) return true;

  if (objectA == null && objectB == null) return true; // depends, do you want two null objects to be treated as equal? If not, use || instead and delete the following line

  if (objectA == null ^ objectB == null) return false;

  return objectA.field1.equals(objectB.field1) &&
         objectA.field2.equals(objectB.field2) &&
         objectA.field3 == objectB.field3 && // in case it's a primitive type
         // and so on
}
```

Obviously you should change the class type you introduce in the method's parameters from `Object` to the specific classes you want to compare.

Then you can just assert the result of this method:

```
assertTrue(compareFields(objectA, objectB));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `equal(Object object)` and `hashCode()` for this:

```
 @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (fieldName != null ? fieldName.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof ClassName)) {
            return false;
        }
        ClassName other = (ClassName) object;
        if ((this.fieldName == null && other.fieldName != null) || (this.fieldName != null && !this.fieldName.equals(other.fieldName))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

hashCode() is a native method and returns the integer hash code value of the object.

The implementation of `hashCode()` can be done using the field you desire to use.
Two or more objects are the same if their hashCodes match, meaning the same int value should be obtained in order to tell that the objects are same.

Comment: A weakness of `hashCode()`: Some complete different words, i.e. caused by different order of same letters, can have the same Hashcode. Like 'otto' and 'toto'.

Comment: I don't think 'otto' and 'toto' produce the same hash. Can you please show it somewhere that they produce the same hash?

Comment: Hmm I read it somewhere, but may be I mixed something up. Then big sorry :-)

Comment: @Asgar it can happen and it's called [hashcode collision](http://www.eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode#hashcode-collisions)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a non recursive `equals` method.

Let's say you classes look like:

```
class A {
    String name;
    B b;
}

class B {
    String name;
    A a;
}
```

For brevity I'm using just fields -- you should write these with private fields and getters.

Then `equals/hashcode` looks like:

```
class A {
  ...
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        B b = (B) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, b.name) && Objects.equals(a.name, b.a.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, a.name);
    }
}
```

Removing the recursion. `B` needs the same treatment.

Of course having this relationship means that if you add or remove a field from `B` you need to change `A`'s `equals/hashcode` implementations.

If you know (because of the way you construct your A and B instances) the `x.equals(y)` implies `x == y` for all instances of `A` and `B` then you can simplify your implementations by using reference equality.